# PCI DSS Compliant – How can I truncation of credit card number using Java.

Tags: java

Our web app need to be made PCI DSS compliant. I have stored encrypted credit card number into database. While retrieving credit card number from database, the card should be masked to view page. Already I was done masked credit card number but PCI DSS complaints needs to be **truncation** of retrieving credit card number. How can I truncation of credit card number using Java application?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried substring?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Already tried substring but PCI DSS needs truncation of credit card number.

Comment: The answer still is: use substring.